# Public company data using Linkedin API?

Tags: web-scraping, linkedin-api

Given a list of companies, I want to get data such as employee count and location, given the name of the company. When I try using the Linkedin APIs, it seems that I am unable to get company profile data unless I am the administrator of the page. Do the Linkedin APIs support this functionality? How would one go about implementing something like this?

Comment: I don't think LinkedIn would allow this, as employment information is generally considered private information.

Comment: I mean the information that is publicly available. For example in the [Stack Exchange Linkedin page](https://www.linkedin.com/company/stack-overflow), I'd like to pull the "201-500 employees" text.

Comment: Oh, Im not sure then.